# Probability of computers sending data

Tags: probability, computer-science, education

Considering the next sentence how am i supposed to calculate it?

> There are 5 computers each with a probability of 0.6 of actually sending data. What is the probability that out of those 5 computers only one sends the data?

I know that the probability should be 1/5 if each computer has a 100% chance of sending data.

Comment: If all $5$ have a $100$ percent chance of sending data then the probability that only one sends data is zero (not $\frac15$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: assuming the events (computer #$k$ sends data) are independent,  the number of computers that send data has a binomial distribution.  That assumption should have been stated.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of each computer sending data is 0.6 then the probability of each computer **not** sending data is 0.4.  The probability of exactly one computer out of five sending data is $\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}(0.6)(0.4)^4= 5(0.6)(0.0256)= 0.0768$.